# how to force python dict to display data as it is ordered

Tags: python, dictionary, unordered

The example marked as duplicate does not address nested dictionaries. Although i tried the example in the `duplicate` that uses `collections.OrderedDict()` but it either gave `list index out of range` or doesnt print anything at all.

The data looks similar to this:

```
[  {
     "name":"frog",
     "age":33,
     "color":"green",
     "weight":86,
     "can_jump": true,
     --- other data and so on ---
  },

  {
    -- other data too ---
  }
]
```

and here is the code i used to retrieve the first four data and store it in the results list.

```
i = 0
while i < len(data_file):
    key = ["name", "age", "color", "weight"]
    results = []
    for x in data_file[i]:
        results.append(data_file[i][x])
    j = 0
    while j < 4:
        print("{}: {}".format(key[j], results[j]))
        j+=1
    print()
    i+=1
```

but when i print out the final ,

results they display randomly like e.g.

```
name: 33
age:86
color: true
weight: green
```

Comment: dicts are unordered, you need an OrderedDict shown in th dupe

Comment: I assume that `data_file[i]` is a dict. You can put your `key = ["name", "age", "color", "weight"]` before the `while` loop; get rid of that `results.append()` loop, and that `j` stuff; and then just do `for k in key:` `print("{}: {}".format(k, data_file[i][k]))`.

Comment: @PM2Ring It worked now. I'm highly grateful

Comment: Generic dictionaries don't preserve order.However you can use sort with item-getter to convert dictionary into a tuple sorted by keys